# No error handling outcome

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

In a database I'm converting, I'm seeing *a lot* of procedures that look like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE DeleteSomething
    @someinput
AS
    DELETE
    FROM [table name]
    WHERE [several conditions are met]
```

I then see these procedures called like so:

```
exec DeleteSomething @someinput
```

However, there's no error handling or anything around the procedure. I'm not very familiar with T-SQL, so I'm trying to check - what happens if this query falls over? If it finds no data? If the conditions aren't met? If the input passed in is null?

1. Am I correct in saying that in *all of these cases* the program will just continue as normal, as @@error hasn't been checked?
2. Similarly, if an output parameter was passed in to the procedure as well and it failed, am I correct in saying it would have a value of null as it hasn't been assigned?

**Edit:**

Here's another example of a query I've come scross:

```
select @variable=field     
from table join othertable on table.id = othertable.id    
where table.id = someinput
```

Again, no error handling. To my knowledge, in Oracle that would throw an error if no data was found. Am I correct in saying in T-SQL it won't, unless the appropriate @error variable is checked?

Comment: If conditions are not met and if input passed is null, result will be  '0 rows affected'.

Comment: @PareshJ: That's what I thought. Maybe it wasn't a great example. I've added an edit to show some of the other non-exception handling cases I'm curious about.

Comment: No much idea about ORACLE but in MSSQL, it would definitely be No records affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: it is not correct. when a stored procedure is called from an external program and something goes wrong on sql side then an error is thrown by sql. what you see here is that this error will not be handled by sql itself. the calling software **may** ignore it but the error is there to be handled by the caller.
btw empty result set and unmet where conditions are not an error.

2: **not sure of that but can't find any evidence or documentation**. if a huge stored procedure (hundreds of lines of code) fails after the value has already been set then the output parameter may not be null.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you are right in assuming that the program will continue to run - ignoring the error. Unless the statement (to exec) is within a try catch block. Another thing to consider is transactions - is the statement in a transaction.

Regarding the second part of your question - I'm (almost) sure that an output parameter would remain unchanged until it is assigned a value. In other words - without a specific example provided by you - you will need to examine a specific SP to find out where a parameter is assigned an value.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `Begin Tran`,`Commit Tran` and `Rollback`

1. First Begin your Transaction with `BEGIN TRAN`
2. IF some rows have been affected based on the query below the `Begin Tran` i.e if `@@ROWCOUNT` is `>=1` the commit your Transaction using COMMIT TRAN
3. If there is some Error and the rows are not got affected then use `ROLLBACK` to rollback your transaction

   ```
   ALTER PROCEDURE DeleteSomething
       @someinput
   AS
   BEGIN TRAN
       DELETE
       FROM [table name]
       WHERE [several conditions are met]
   IF @@Trancount>=1
   Begin
     COMMIT TRAN
   End
   ELSE
   BEGIN
     Rollback
   END
   IF @@Errorcount<>0
     ROLLBACK TRAN
     Declare @ErrMsg Nvarchar(8000),@ErrSeverity int
     Select @ErrMsg=ERROR_MESSSAGE(),@ErrSeverity=ERROR_SEVERITY()
     Raiserror(@ErrMsg,@ErrSeverity,1)
   ```

Comment: This is good code, but it doesn't answer the questions I've asked.